# Jitsi External API configuration

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm new with Jitsi and I'm trying to configure the Jitsi External API on my Django project. I have created the video call as below.

```
const domain = 'meet.jit.si';
const options = {
    roomName: 'BeehobMeetExample',
    width: 1100,
    height: 700,
    parentNode: document.querySelector('#meet'),
    userInfo: {
        email: '{{request.user.email}}',
        displayName: '{{request.user.first_name}} ' + '{{request.user.last_name}}',
        avatarUrl: '{{ request.user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}'
    },
    configOverwrite: {
        prejoinPageEnabled: false
    },
    interfaceConfigOverwrite: { TILE_VIEW_MAX_COLUMNS: 2 },
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
```

Now, I'm trying to set one person selected by the moderator to be a `guest` like a camera and audio on, and other room attendees `only listeners`. Also I'm trying to show the role in the `userInfo`. Could you please help me with these?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the buttons of the toolbar with the conditionals you need but in general, using the Jitsi iframe has its limitation because the UI and core functionalities are from Jitsi itself